# Can't allocate render-less component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a screen and I need to allocate a list of components (Call) to do some logic without returning a jsx to render in this screen

I tried using FlatList by writing:

(1) In renderless component (Call) (Call.js):

```
  render() {
    return null;
  }
```

(2) In the screen which I need to allocate the renderless component list in (OutGoingCallScreen.js):

```
  renderCall = ({ call }) => {
    <Call
      callId={call.callId}
      isVideo={this.props.isVideo}
      isIncoming={this.props.isIncoming}
    />;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      ...
      ...
      <FlatList data={this.props.calls} renderItem={renderCall} />
      ...
      ...
      ...
  );
  }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: renderCall
```

Comment: Try "renderItem={this.renderCall}" in your render instead of just "renderItem={renderCall}". Let me know if that works and post a proper answer for you.

Comment: thanks, error solved

Answer (score 0):

Just confirmed in the comments, but it looks like all you're missing is "this" before renderCall:

`<FlatList data={this.props.calls} renderItem={this.renderCall} />`

Instead of:

`<FlatList data={this.props.calls} renderItem={renderCall} />`